# What is donnyworld service?

Tags: networking, services

There is a port listed on my centos box in /etc/services with tcp and udp port number 1821 for "donnyworld". I've looked up and down Google for a description and can't find anything! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What is donnyworld service?

> In the summer of 1994 DonnyWorld, Inc. created the original Real-Time Animation Chat(tm). This DOS-based client-server product, unique and ahead of its time, was marketed to operators of asynchronous dial-up on-line systems (BBS's), during the period that the Internet was in its infancy. We operated our first full-time 8-line Real-Time Animation Chat(tm) server during the summer of 1995, and garnered favorable reviews in the Boston Globe and the Mass High Tech journal by autumn of 1995.

Source http://www.aboutus.com/DonnyWorld.com

You can find more information about donnyworld.com on the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20060208193220/http://donnyworld.com/index.htm).

> [image]

The domain is currently unused.

---

```
Service Name Port Number Transport Protocol Description Assignee     Contact
```

...

```
donnyworld   1821        tcp                donnyworld  [Don_Oliver] [Don_Oliver]
donnyworld   1821        udp                donnyworld  [Don_Oliver] [Don_Oliver]
```

...

```
ID Name      Organization Contact URI
```

...

```
[Don_Oliver] Don Oliver   mailto:don&donnyworld.com
```

Source [Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml)

Answer (score 2):

Donnyworld is a now dead "Animation Chat" protocol.

If you want to know more, you can search the Internet Archive Wayback machine for donnyworld.com.

The entry should probably be removed from /etc/services upstream, as the protocol is dead and the contact person for the entry can no longer be reached.